# Windows 10 K&N Edition Anniversary update - Media player update not working

Tags: windows-10, mp3, windows-media-player, thumbnails

I own a Windows 10 K or N Edition which doesn't include the media player package. My problem is: I want to have preview thumbnails in the explorer for my MP3s and videos.

I had the issue before when I updated to Win10 but there [this update](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49919) saved me. Since the **Anniversary update** they are gone again.

Now I can install the old update but I still don't get the media player nor the preview images.

I tried most of the things Microsoft offers me but they are either not installable or don't work.

Any ideas what might be the correct update package?

Thx!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Features Pack (KB3133719 which supercedes KB3099229) for Windows 10 Anniversary Update is right here:

[Download Media Feature Pack for N versions of Windows 10 from Official Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356)

And the corresponding MS Knowledgebase article is at [Media Feature Pack for N editions of Windows 10 Version 1607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3133719)

Src: [Where is Windows Media Player in Windows 10?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-media-player-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 Creators Update v1703 (Build 15063), you need to install the [Update KB4016817](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017)

**Download:**
[32Bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/E/C/9EC0EC2C-8151-468A-95A3-2F2AD6A2AC13/Microsoft-Windows-MediaFeaturePack-OOB-Package_x86.msu)
[64Bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/E/C/9EC0EC2C-8151-468A-95A3-2F2AD6A2AC13/Microsoft-Windows-MediaFeaturePack-OOB-Package.msu)

This also restores the Game Mode/XBox entry in the settings app, which is new in Creators Update.

For Windows 10 Fall Creators Update v1709 (Build 16299.15), you need to install the [Update KB4039813](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039813/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-october-2017) from [Downloadcenter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack)

For Windows 10 April 2018 Update (Version 1803 - Build 17134.x), you need to install the Update [KB4057437](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057437/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-april-2018) from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack).