# Upgrade Windows 10 N to non-N

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have an MSDN account and installed Windows 10 N on some gaming machines thinking they didn't need Windows Media Player in the past. Now I'm regretting that as the Media Pack doesn't install all needed DLLs and some games don't work.

To fix this, I would like to upgrade to the non-N version. There are plenty of keys in my MSDN account, but for some reason, when doing an in-place install, it's not giving me the option of keeping my apps, only my files.

Why is this? Is there a special way to do an in-place upgrade and keep my apps?

Comment: Your attempting to use a Windows Professional key, correct?

Comment: Correct. Pro to Pro.

Comment: [Your](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro) using one of those methods to go to Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1113816/windows-10-kn-edition-anniversary-update-media-player-update-not-working/1200146#1200146) for links to media pack of 1607 and 1703

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just install the media feature pack?  I did this successfully on one or two technet-then upgraded to windows 10 N licenses that I installed GTA Five on which requires the media feature pack that is not normally with N installations.

Does this link work for you?:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231

Comment: Installing the Media Pack doesn't solve all the issues. I've come up against many strange ones where certain games or apps just don't work right or at all. I ended up doing an in-place upgrade.